# Monogame children update method lag

Tags: c#, monogame

So I'm pretty new to computer programming, but I know the basics of C#.

I'm working on a Monogame project and was making an update method for my sprites. Since my sprites are terraria based (I mean that every sprite is a different bodypart) I made a children list. In that list I put all the body sprites and I attach the list to a parent (center sprite of the player).

This is my basic sprite update method: (not only for player)

```
public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
{
    timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

    if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
        timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
        ++currentFrame.X;

        if (currentFrame.X >= sheetSize.X)
        {
            currentFrame.X = 0;
            ++currentFrame.Y;

            if (currentFrame.Y >= sheetSize.Y)
            {
                currentFrame.Y = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my player sprite update method in another class:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
{
    position += direction;

    // If sprite moves off screen
    if (position.X < 0)
    {
        position.X = 0;
    }

    if (position.Y < 0)
    {
        position.Y = 0;
    }

    if (position.X > clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X)
    {
        position.X = clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X;
    }

    if (position.Y > clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y)
    {
        position.Y = clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y;
    } 

    // Continue base update method 
    base.Update(gameTime, clientBounds);
}
```

And this is the draw method, wich works just fine:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
    player.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
    player.children.ForEach(c => c.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch));
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

But the update method is lagging:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    player.children.Add(playerDeux);
    float millisecondsRunning = 30;
    float millisecondsWalking = millisecondsRunning  * 2f;

    if (player.running == true)
    {
        player.millisecondsPerFrame = millisecondsRunning;
    }

    else if (player.running == false)
    {
        player.millisecondsPerFrame = 65;
        playerDeux.millisecondsPerFrame = 30;
    }

    if (player.walking == false)
    {
        player.textureImage = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/" + s1[1]);
    }

    player.Update(gameTime, Game.Window.ClientBounds);
    player.children.ForEach(c => c.Update(gameTime, Game.Window.ClientBounds));
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

So when I call the draw method on all the children it works just fine, but when I call the Update method on the children it lags very much and the program even stops working.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: also note that this class is not done yet, it's just a test where I draw 2 sprites and update (animation plays) them.
+ The s1[1] in player.textureImage = Game.Content.Load(@"Images/" + s1[1]); is just a string name in an array.

Comment: The lag is visible in the very beginning in the game but you can see some movement (very little movement), and increases very rapidly. The game just freezes after ~ 5 sec.

Comment: I don't know enough to post an answer, but that `Load<Texture2D>()` call looks awfully suspicious. I hope it's not reloading a texture from disk for every object each frame...

Comment: That load<Texture2D<() just uses a string out an  array of image names. It's just so I can choose wich animation plays and I can rapidly change it by changing the string in the array. But I think it's not a good use of an array so I will look into it

Comment: @Jelle I don't think you're right about that. The `Load` method actually loads the texture from disk every time - hence why you should typically load textures in your `LoadContent` method.

Comment: Yes, but I meant that my method was wrong. I didn't think of that when I wrote that class -_-  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some oddities with your code, but I think the main culprit is the `player.children.Add(playerDeux)`. The way it is right now, you're adding `playerDeux` to the children list every single update, and then updating `playerDeux` once for every time `Update` has already run. It looks like you want to move this line of code to your `Initialize` or `LoadContent` methods.

Also, you should probably load the texture only once in the `LoadContent` method and only reference the in-memory texture in the `Update` method. This isn't the main reason the game is this much laggy, but it is an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thank you! I made a mistake some time ago and couldn't use that line in Loadcontent so I placed it in the Update method temporarily, but forgot to put it back in the Loadcontent() method.